# Copy assignment operator for diamond inheritance C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have 4 classes in a diamond inheritance hierarchy. Is it right to call both parents' assignment operator for the assignment operator in `der12` class? Wouldn't it call the `base` operator= 2 times? Is there a better way to do it?

````
    protected:
        int a = 1;

    public:
        base& operator=(const base& ref){
            ...
        }
};

class der1 : virtual public base{
    protected:
        int b = 2;
    
    public:
        der1& operator=(const der1& ref){
            ...
        }
};

class der2 : virtual public base{
    protected:
        int c = 3;
        
    public:
        der2& operator=(const der2& ref){
            ...
        }
};

class der12 : public der1, public der2{
    int d = 4;

    public:
        der12& operator=(const der12& ref){
            der1::operator=(ref);
            der2::operator=(ref);
            d = ref.d;
            
            return *this;
        }
};```
````

Comment: Your assignment operator for `der12` doesn't call the copy constructor for either `der1` or `der2`.

Comment: @Peter it calls the assignment operator from `der1` and `der2` I edited my post now, thanks!

Comment: You can separate the assignment logic for each class, and put it in a protected member function. Then call the the ones you need from the assignment operator in each class.

Comment: This goes to show why you should __never__ do diamond inheritance. They are in practice, always a bad idea.